# Output of programs in vim using SingleCompile

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Using [SingleCompile](https://github.com/xuhdev/SingleCompile) in vim, if I run `:SCCompileRun` on a file like

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    char s[100];
    printf("Enter some text to store in s\n");
    scanf("%s" , s );
    printf("\n%s\n", s);
    return ;
}
```

I get an output like :

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
abc
Enter some text to store in s

abc

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I see `Enter some text to store in s` after the entire program runs. Is it possible to get the output of the program as it executes?

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` after the printf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @FDinoff, fflush(stdout) worked.